# Is there any solution for Google Scripts getCharts().getAs error?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

I've one google script running since a few months without any problems, last week a scheduled email that was sent on weekly basis stoped working without any reason further than:

```
Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id XXX
```

I was able to narrow down the problem to the call to getCharts().getAs() section, and it seems that there are many users having the same problem, and of course the solution goes from starting all over again, creating new scripts and so on.
I've found this issue in google [bugtracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/182701055?pli=1), but nothing concrete so far, and this report is highly important.

I've tried using getCharts().getBlob(), getOptions(), calling the spreadsheet by id or getActiveSpreadsheet(), creating all from scratch, but same error keeps happening.

Any solution, idea?

Comment: Tried making a copy of spreadsheet?

Comment: @TheMaster I’ve even made it from scratch….